# np.argmax to return -1 if all values in the input are the same

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use `np.argmax` but I want to get -1 (or any other number) when all the elements in the array input are the same or if there are multiple occurences of them. For example, `a = np.array([2, 2, 2])` -> I want to get -1 instead of 0. Is there any alternative function?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of such a function, but you could always write it yourself, e.g. like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def my_index(arr):
    """
    Input: arr should be a NumPy array.
    Return -1 if at least one number in arr occurs more than once.
    Else return the index of the maximum number.
    """
    flat = arr.ravel()
    if len(np.unique(flat)) < len(flat):
        return -1
    return np.argmax(arr)
```

Comment: On my machine, `set` takes 1.7x and 4.7x the time taken by `np.unique` for 1000 and 1M elements respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Guimoute. I have replaced `set` with `np.unique`.